# How to default a select list to have no elements selected for use with jQuery bsmSelect plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, html, asmselect

I'm using the jQuery bsmSelect plugin to give my users a convenient way to select multiple options from a select-drop-down list. It works well, except I need it to start with nothing selected by default. Anyone know how this can be accomplished?

bsmSelect intro:
http://www.ryancramer.com/journal/entries/select_multiple/

Comment: FYI: *If the SELECT element has the multiple attribute set and more than one OPTION element has the selected attribute set, they should all be pre-selected.* http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/interact/forms.html#h-17.6.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HTMLSelectElement.selectedIndex = -1;`

> The ordinal index of the selected option, starting from 0. **The value -1 is returned if no element is selected.** If multiple options are selected, the index of the first selected option is returned.

http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-94282980